# Insert Value in 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to add multiple data in 2 sheets. With that I have an error:

> Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set

Referring to this line:

```
With Sheetclient = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CMB_Test.Value)
```

The first page is chosen by a combobox value and it's working well, and the second page will automatically *something* the page: "testbit".

```
  Private Sub Save_test_Click()

Dim Sheetclient As Worksheet
Dim testbit1 As Worksheet
Dim nr As Integer, lr As Integer

 With Sheetclient = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CMB_Test.Value)
 nr = Sheetclient.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheetclient.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.TB_dateBit.Value
 Sheetclient.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.serial.Value
 Sheetclient.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.matrice.Value
 Sheetclient.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.CMB_config.Value
 Sheetclient.Cells(nr, 9) = Me.lifetime.Value

 End With

 With testbit1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("testbit")
 nr = testbit1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 testbit1.Cells(nr, 1) = Me.TB_dateBit.Value
 testbit1.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.serial.Value
 testbit1.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.matrice.Value
 testbit1.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.CMB_config.Value
 testbit1.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.lifetime.Value
 End with

 End

 End Sub
```

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281759/simple-vba-code-gives-me-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-not-set of any help? Usually you need to `set` the object...

Comment: Check the VBA docs for correct use of With

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Set` the object - and having `Set` it, you can use `.` to reference it. Thus your code might look like this:

```
Set Sheetclient = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CMB_Test.Value)
With Sheetclient
  nr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  .Cells(nr, 5) = Me.TB_dateBit.Value
  .Cells(nr, 6) = Me.serial.Value
  .Cells(nr, 7) = Me.matrice.Value
  .Cells(nr, 8) = Me.CMB_config.Value
  .Cells(nr, 9) = Me.lifetime.Value
End With
```

Same for the second part of the code

Comment: It'S doesn't work with the second one. I have en error message:Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Comment: That error message suggests that you don't have a sheet called "testbit" in `ThisWorkbook`. You could try `Workbooks("name of workbook").Sheets("name of sheet")` - rather than referencing `ThisWorkbook`. Sometimes that works better.